# Figure at the wrong vertical and horizontal position

Tags: graphics, eps

I'm trying to add an eps figure to my document. 
I'm using Texniccenter 2.02 and Miktex.

In the output document the picture moves about a third to the right and to the top. It then exceeds the page border. If I set a frame around the figure with `\fbox{\includegraphics{..}}` the frame appears at the correct position, but the figure is still on the top, right corner.

Using other pictures is not a problem.

I exported the picture from coreldraw X5

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: I suspect a problem with the bounding box of the EPS file.

Comment: provide the image to download for a test.

Comment: Yes, there appears to be something wrong with the boundingbox. I opened the file with GsView and redrew the boundingbox. However, now the picture is moved towards the bottom lft corner, but not as much anymore.

Comment: I suggest you convert it to .pdf with `epspdftk` (a Windows version of epspdf, which is a luatex script that interfaces with ghostscript) and computes exact bounding boxes.

Answer (score 0):

I had a very similar issue using CorelDraw 7.

I found that when I changed texnic center to convert in the following order the problem went away Latex -> PS -> PDF instead of Latex -> DVI -> PDF.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! In as much does this answer the question?